# I can't get a directory to show up on my website even though directory is listed on the directory

Tags: php

I have been at it for 3 days with getting my website to show a specific url that I tried to create through the java terminal control for an ubuntu based website.

I've successfully gotten everything else to work but one thing, is that when I go to /var/www/html the root directory for anything viewed by the public. Then when I go in and use ls to have it list the names only index.html exist and I cannot delete it no matter how many times I use rm in any way I can. But when I go to /var/www/ and have it list the files in it it shows the file I created which was mytest.php
with a line of code but everytime I enter my (url)/mytest.php it will say the url does not exist I am wondering why.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file called index.html, that file will be displayed (depending on your configuration) instead of listing the contents of the directory. This may also apply to some other files called index - e.g. index.php, index.htm, etc.

Comment: I know that, but I was talking about when I go to my url/mytest.php in which the file is located in the root directory it would not show that the url exists at all.

Comment: it would be easier if I could upload an image